# apt-get update not reporting upgradable packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and somehow I have apt in a weird state. performing an `sudo apt-get update` goes through all the motions and returns no error, however it doesn't not report any upgradable packages. If I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` it will install the available updates.
I have tried to repair with the following commands:
'
sudo dpkg --config -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken'

Is there anything else I can do to try and repair this situation?

EDIT:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease [267 kB]       
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 focal InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease               
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease         
Fetched 603 kB in 2s (324 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
savaho@BlackHole:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
```

Comment: Please try `sudo apt update`, this should give you the information about how many packages can be upgraded.

Comment: forgot to list it, but I have use that as well.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1387310/edit) your question to add the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: So where is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: `apt` is a wrapper for several commands, including `apt-get`.  The 2 commands are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Bovine The output of both commands is different, while `apt update` will tell you how many packages can be upgraded, `apt-get update` will not.

Comment: @mook765 since OP has stated that both `update` and `upgrade` have already been run, and without error, would there be any additional info to be gleaned from running the commands again?

Comment: @Bovine The benefit in doing so is that you see the difference in the output of both commands which I stated in my previous command.

Comment: @mook765 you should probably post that as the answer ...

Comment: If `apt update` is telling you that you have no available updates, then why do you believe that you have available updates?

Comment: Did you opt to install updates during the installation? If so, you won't have any updates after you reboot and start using the OS. Updates will come later.